# How to add block layered filter(Layered Navigation module) to manufacturers page in prestashop

Tags: php, module, prestashop, prestashop-1.6

I want to add block layered filter (Layered Navigation module) and features to manufacturers products page on the left  block.

while selecting category menu the category/manifacture filter is showing in category page, but same filter i need in manufacture page while clicking in manufacture menu.

Please help if anybody knows.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

There is no such option for Manufacturer pages.

One solution would be not to use the manufacturer page but link all your manufacturers to their corresponding Categorie's result page. For example, if your main category is "1-all-products" then the manufacturer Toyota's page will be : `http://www.example.com/1-all-products#/manufacturer-toyota`.

Comment: pls can u tell how to link all your manufacturers to their corresponding Categories result page because manufacture menu is also in top menu bar,so if we click to manufacture menu how it will show all category/manufacture filter in side bar.

Comment: You're asking a broad question, I answer a rapid response. If you want more help, please edit your question and provide what you've tried so far.